# Get Authorization realm from logon user (in Windows domain)

Tags: c++, windows, qt, http, authorization

I try to download something from my own webserver. This webserver exists only in the intranet and so I want to use the Active Directory to manage my usernames and passwords. My webserver has Windows authentification activated, so the user can enter the service without entering his username and password again. With the browsers (Chrome and Internet Explorer) everything works absoluley well.

**My Problem:**

My application contacts the server via QNetworkAccessManager (Qt). This class does not support NTLM/Negotiate very well. I've make it work with winhttp (C++) but i need the solution in Qt (QNetworkAccessManager). My real problem is getting the authorization realm f.e.:

> Authorization: Negotiate TlRMAAl4IIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGAAAADw==

So I've searched for approximatly 2 days to find more information about this key. At the moment I know that I have to use SSPI and [AcquireCredentialsHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374712%28VS.85%29.aspx) function to get this key, but I don't really know how to get this to work. I'm not absolutey sure that this is the correct function but i saw some simlar code in the Google Chrome (chromium) source-code.

**Does anybody know how to get this authorization key from a logged on user (in a windows domain) from Windows itself without entering the password again?**

Environment:

- OS: Win XP and 7 (x64)